# How to set Extjs ComboBox valueField dynamically?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have two combo boxes set to same store

combo1

```
xtype: 'combo',
store: client_store,
queryMode: 'local',
displayField: 'mem_id',
valueField: 'mem_id',
....
```

combo2

```
xtype: 'combo',
store: client_store,
queryMode: 'local',
displayField: 'mem_name',
valueField: 'mem_name',
```

so first one used to search and select by member id and second one for member name

is there way to use one combo box instead of two and set valueField & displayField dynamically ?

Regards

Comment: does the user see only one combo on the page at a time?

Comment: currently user see both. but what i wana do is use one combo box for both actions

Comment: setup an additional field in your store. call it display_name or something and use the Ext.data.Field.convert to concatenate name and id. convert:function(v,r){return r.get('mem_name')+' ('+r.get('mem_id')+')'} then set the combo's display field to this display_name. this way, in the dropdown, you will now see "Gihan Lasita (71)" instead of just Gihan Lasita or just 71

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you interact with remote source, you can use Ext.data.HttpProxy combined with Ext.data.JsonReader to do that. Well written example : http://www.sk-typo3.de/ExtJS-Dynamische-Comboboxen.337.0.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. in my case i want to use one store and use the same box to load data